# Confusion about An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I  am  fallowing an example  .I have a field  named  Deleted in the db. .When I click the delete button actually not deleting data just  replcaing "N" with "Y"  value The problem is   i downloaded  the source code It works but  after slightly changed  I get this exception.I am wondering what am i doing wrong

this code works

```
         if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
         {

        long holidayNum = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);




        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Deleted", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "Y";

                cmd.CommandText = "Update HolidaysDetails set Deleted=@Deleted where HolidayNum=" + holidayNum;

                con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                cmd.Connection = con;




                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {

                    con.Open();

                }

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                dlHoliday.EditItemIndex = -1;

                GetData();

            }

        }




    }
```

But my code throws an exception

```
      if (e.CommandName.Equals("delete"))
    {

        long holidayNum = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);
         cmdText = "Update  HolidaysDetails set Deleted=@deleted where HolidayNum"  
         + holidayNum;
        using (con = new SqlConnection(cnnStr))
        {

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {

                con.Open();
            }
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "Y";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                dlHoliday.EditItemIndex = -1;
                GetData();


            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply missing the equal sign here

```
cmdText = "Update  HolidaysDetails set Deleted=@deleted " + 
           "where HolidayNum=" + holidayNum;
                            ^
```

By the way, while you are trying to follow the correct practices and use a parameter for the `@deleted` flag, you are doing it wrong. [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires, as second parameter, the value not the parameter type. While at fixing it, add also the second parameter required by the query

```
cmdText = "Update  HolidaysDetails set Deleted=@deleted " + 
          "where HolidayNum=@num";
......
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", "Y");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", holidaynum);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
....
```